# In unity 5 export package is not working correctly

Tags: unity

I am using unity 5. I Created an objects with layer names. I tried to export a package. After Exporting, i import the package in new project and ran the project its not working. observed that objects layer name is missing for all the objects. i attached the screenshot with this.

Before Export :
[image]

After Import the Exported Package : 
[image]
In layer drop down box no layer name was found. only the default layer name is available. if anyone knows the answer please tell me.

Comment: you are right ! layers and tags are one of few stuff that don't export from the package . It's because there is chance of layer or tag conflict.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you import the project settings you will have to create the layers in the new project. In some cases it would be nice if the layers names would export/import being recognized as a required resource in the package. Especially if say it was a unity asset package that needed it and someone without knowledge just bought the package.

Now if you copied the whole folder zipped it up and the new user drops the files in including the settings they will get the project settings will overwrite box. and if you ok it the layers will be added along with everything else such as the tags and even the editor windows and all the settings.

Comment: but unity will export the package with layer name right? how can i do that?

Comment: That will only happen if you copy either the whole project folder or the project settings within the project. Then if you opened it from another project or machine all the settings would be the same.

Comment: I am trying to copy the whole project only

Comment: For this reason, I usually include tags in a static class of a utility namespace, and include a debug log to alert that "tag x is not in use and can not be found."